# Using NOLOCK for reading single static row. Whats the harm?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

Can anyone with DEADLOCK experience enlighten me?

I read that it can cause log file corruption - is that possible? I think MS would never do that. Also if "some situations", like mine, are okay with DEADLOCK, why not use it?

I have no datasets, return tables (like other posts in Stack Overflow). I have one SQL statement with ID select which returns only one row like:

```
 sqlstr = "SELECT Parameter1 FROM Companies WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ID = 25
```

Also, this parameter does not change. But as this is a heavy load aspnet application (not a web site) and I run this kind of query again and again, every SQL read causes a lock in SQL server. If possible I'd prefer to avoid that.

Every post in this site is about multiple records, recordsets, dirty reads. I could not find anything about "reading single record which is not changing all the time".

Any expert's opinion, please?

Comment: If you will only ever read a single row, with `ID` that never changes, why not create a filtered index? You would then read off the index instead of the table.

Comment: Why not utilize SqlCacheDependency in the app so it doesn't slam your db so much?

Comment: What's the harm? What's the benefit? If the row is static it won't be locked anyway probably and SQL Server will also skip taking row level S locks anyway if the page doesn't contain any uncommitted changes.

Comment: I don't see any reasons for a deadlock here. Do you actually see them? As to your question, in short - you don't need this hint, since readers never block other readers, regardless of the TIL used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After deep searches and asking questions to many experts I found out that using NOLOCK hint causes no problem in this scenario, yet its not advised. nothing wrong with NOLOCK but as I use sql2014 I "should" use ISOLATION LEVEL option. Its a method came instead of NOLOCK. For example for huge table selects that cause deadlocks:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
SELECT * FROM HugeTable;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

is very handy.

I had HugeTable and a web form that uses sqlAdapter and Radgrid to show this data. Whenever I run this report, though indexes and paging of radgrid is fine, it caused deadlock, which makes sense. I changed select statement of sqlAdapter to above sentence, its perfect now.

best.

Answer (score 0):

This simple select statement when executed without any lock/nolock hints under default transaction isolation level , obtains a shared lock on the row, It means other users can also read this row while its being read by this query.

On the other hand when you specify `WITH (NOLOCK)` query hint, it does not obtain any locks at all. In this case again other users can read this row as well but you might be reading a dirty row (data that has not been committed to disk yet and is in the process of being modified).

So in either case this simple select will not cause a deadlock. So really the question you should be asking yourself is, should users be able to see dirty data or not? and in most cases the answer would be no.

Therefore do not worry about getting deadlocks with this select query. as long as you are using default transaction isolation level. In a more strict isolation level like seriallizable a select can lock out other users but in default isolation level you should be ok.

Comment: This select can cause a deadlock if it uses an index and a key lookup. Writes lock in the reverse order than this query would.

Answer (score 0):

`NOLOCK` has two main disadvantages: It can return uncommitted data (you don't seem worried about that) and it can cause queries to spuriously fail under very rare circumstances. Never will `NOLOCK` cause physical database corruption.

Consider using snapshot isolation for transactions that only read data. Readers under SI do not lock or block. SI takes them out of the picture. It provides perfect consistency for read-only transactions. Be sure to find out about the drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't worth it.

NOLOCK is often exploited as a magic way to speed up database reads, but I try to avoid using it whever possible.

The result set can contain rows that have not yet been committed, that are often later rolled back.

An error or Result set can be empty, be missing rows or display the same row multiple times.

This is because other transactions are moving data at the same time you're reading it.

READ COMMITTED adds an additional issue where data is corrupted within a single column where multiple users change the same cell simultaneously.

There are other side-effects too, which result in sacrificing the speed increase you were hoping to gain in the first place.

Now you know, never use it again.